# Selecting the highest value in SQL

Tags: sql-server, join, adventureworks

I want to select the highest value, I have joined two tables and I want to be able to find the highest value as well as the persons first name.

I have my column called `SalesYTD` which is in my `Sales.Salesperson` table. And my `Firstname` column which is in my `person.person` table.

I want to find only the highest value in the `SalesYTD` table and display it along with the persons `Firstname`.

I've tried the following query:

```
SELECT FirstName, MAX(SalesYTD) AS YTD 
FROM Person.Person 
JOIN Sales.SalesPerson ON Person.Person.BusinessEntityID = Sales.SalesPerson.BusinessEntityID
GROUP BY FirstName, SalesYTD
```

Comment: Please show your complete query.

Answer (score 1):

A query has a `SELECT`.  The answer to your question is to use `TOP (1)` and `ORDER BY`.

Presumably, the query looks like:

```
SELECT TOP (1) FirstName, SalesYTD
FROM Person p JOIN
     Sales.SalesPerson sp
     ON p.BusinessEntityID = sp.BusinessEntityID
ORDER BY SalesYTD DESC;
```